# How to toggle office-ui-fabric detailslist row selection using the entire row as a toggle instead of just using the small tiny checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

I'm using Office UI Fabric React components and i'm trying to improve change the default selection behavior for a [DetailsList](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/detailslist). By default, there is a difference between clicking a row and clicking the tiny checkbox on the right. I want the same effects of the checkbox click to apply to the row click.

When you click the checkbox it **toggles** the row and does not deselect other rows like when I use a row click. You can also use shift click and control click and all the other nice types of clicks as well here.

**How can I make it so that clicking on a row has the same functionality as clicking on one of the checkboxes?**
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this custom onRenderRow function for the DetailsList:

```
onRenderRow = (props: IDetailsRowProps, defaultRender?: IRenderFunction<IDetailsRowProps>): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <div data-selection-toggle="true">
        {defaultRender && defaultRender(props)}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Works for both SelectionMode.multiple and SelectionMode.single: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YoEzzE

Comment: Super clean solution! Thanks!

Comment: The `data-selection-toggle` prop no longer seems to have any effect, do you know what it has changed to?

Comment: Can you provide a codepen/jsfiddle where it doesn't work? The above example still works even though it auto-upgraded to Fabric 7.

Comment: Works great but it brokes MarqueeSelection. Do you have any idea how to fix it?